# How to increase the size of cache or local-storage in ipad2

Tags: ios, cordova, caching, local-storage

I am developing an iOS app for iPad-2 with the help of phone-gap. In that I am saving selected details in local-storage(or cache). But some times the file size may exceed the default local-storage size 5.0 MB. In this case I need to increase the local-storage (or cache) file size manually or pragmatically.

Can any one help me on this for fixing this issue?

Thank you.

Comment: You cannot change this value. If you need more storage you need to look to native solutions.

Comment: Thank you Dawson for your suggestion. Can you please suggest any approach for increasing the size of the cache so that It can be more use full to me.

Comment: @user3500377 You can use SQLite database to increase your local storage requirement. see [here](https://github.com/brodysoft/Cordova-SQLitePlugin) for details.

Comment: I'd ditto frank - use SQLite for your 'big' storage needs. Or use the file system. Both of this is fairly easy with PhoneGap.